# List products related to currently active category (url)

Tags: category, request, querystring

My URL:
http://localhost/product-family/compressors

How can I list the related products? 
I don't understand how to get access to the `compressors` (a category entry of the product-family category type). The product-family is a structure - so there may be many levels.

(I thought I'd have access to the currently selected category via `entry` but I get error when I try to access it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as `entry` is available if you hit an entry, the variable `category` is available if you hit a category.

Thus the following code:

```
{% if category is defined %}
    {# Specific category selected #}             
{% else %}
    {# No specific category selected #}
{% endif %}
```